# How to count comma separated specific value from a single cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to count comma separated specific values in a single cell in excel.
Suppose to found how many 15's are there in a single cell that contains 15,115,1515,15,215,15
I need the result 3.
Is there any formula in excel

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

Comment: @JvdV I thought of that, but then considered that `FILTERXML` probably wouldn't differentiate `015` and `15` and `15.00`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld and your idea is that it should or should not count towards n? `//s[.='15']` does not take `015` or `15.00` as the same inputs.

Comment: @JvdV Ah. My error. I was using `.=15` and not `.= '15'`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to compare the length of the original value with the length of the value after you've replaced all the 15s with a zero-length string, and divide that by 4 (which is the length of ",15,").

One important note... make sure to add a comma to the start and end of the original string to pick up leading and trailing 15s.

Here's what it would look like...
[image]